# Is there any way to transfer the user to the Settings -> Keyboards screen in iOS programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, settings, ios-keyboard-extension

I'm new to iOS development and I'm currently working on a Keyboard Extension for iOS. I'm looking for a quick way to transfer the user using code to the Settings -> Keyboards screen so the user could grant my keyboard extension the "Allow Full Access" permission.

Testing other vendors that create keyboard extensions none of them have completed this task. Is there any way to achieve this, or I'm out of luck and it's not allowed by Apple?

Comment: I don't believe there is.  Until iOS8 there wasn't even a way for an application to open it's own settings page.

Comment: Yeah, but now with iOS8 release, things have changed... keyboard extensions are added. Like in the Android platform the user should be able to go to his current keyboard settings. I can't understand why wouldn't they allow it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can open the settings-app by using [`UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
```

This code will open your apps custom settings, if it has any. It may not possible to open other specific tabs like the keyboard-tab, but it's the right way to go.